# Find the domain and range of the function, $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x+y}$ and sketch the domain in the xy-plane.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have found the domain to be $y \geq -x$.

I have found the range to be $z \geq 0$, or $[ 0, \infty )$.

I'm not sure how to sketch the domain in the xy-plane. I figured it would be a straight line through $(0,0)$ with $-1$ slope, and the values in the domain would be everything above that line, but I seem to be wrong.

Comment: Your domain is the half plane bounded by the line $y=-x$, and containing both the line $y=-x$ and the point $(0,1)$.

Comment: Finding the domain of a function makes no sense.  If you know the function, then you know its domain. You can, however, find the "natural domain" of an expression.

Comment: Lol. I was given a function and I found it's domain. Makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer. I just needed the attach picture feature to show the domain of the function, which is the hatched region.

Hope it helps

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: So this would be the final sketch of the domain correct? It also goes infinitely in the x and y direction to the right and upwards right?

Comment: Yes it is an half plane. You can see it as the $y\ge 0$ halfplane rotated by $45°$ clockwise